# NameError and AttributeError while inserting variables in SQLite3 table with Tkinter?

Tags: python, database, tkinter, sqlite

I wanted to make a text-file manager, but I'm stuck at the login/sign-up page. My program takes inputs (Name, Last name, username and password) from the user and stores them all in a database. However, I can't retrieve the said data because every time I try, I end up with either a NameError (uname not defined (uname is global everywhere)) or an AttributeError (str object does not have .get()). Here is a small piece of my code:

```
def login_check():
  global password, uname
  checkpass=cur.execute("SELECT Password from Sample WHERE Uname = (?);",(uname.get()),)
  conn.commit;
  if checkpass==password.get():
      mainscreen()
  else:
      mb.showerror('Login Failed','Username or Password incorrect. Please retry.')
```

Here's how I've taken the entry for the username in a different function:

```
uname=Entry(spp)
uname.grid(row=3, column=1)
cur.execute("insert into Sample values (?, ?, ?, ?)", (fname.get(), lname.get(), uname.get(), password.get()));
```

The program ran well and didn't show the errors only until recently. I can't add the entire code here because it is too large, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could suggest what I could do to improve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This a workaround from me to check if the data inserted in the entry is valid data in db. Since you didn't paste column name for password i did it `P_word` change that to password column name in your table.

This will check if the data is valid before it will open the main `window` if not `messagebox` will pop up. Make sure you close the login window after opening main window.

```
def login_check():
  global password, uname

  con = sqlite3.connect("database_name.db") # your database should be name
  cur = con.cursor()

  attempt = ("SELECT * FROM Password WHERE Uname=? AND P_word=?") # column to check name n password
  cur.execute(attempt, (uname.get(), password.get()))
  rows = cur.fetchall()

  if rows:
      mainscreen()
  else:
      mb.showerror('Login Failed','Username or Password incorrect. Please retry.')
```

Comment: You can comment if you need any assistant.

Comment: @Soumya Mukhija if the answer solves your problem make sure you tick it as reference for future coders.